# Looking for a FREE Cloud based 'Web Mapping Stack' Host

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations

Any pointers to free cloud-based geoweb hosts? Use case: To display a basic interactive web map in Leaflet/ OpenLayers with data hosted in PostGIS served by GeoServer. I am looking at something very close to the [OpenGeoSuite](http://opengeo.org) since I am playing with that at the moment already. [This is basically a teach-yourself webmapping exercise and there are zero personally hosted server resources on my sleeves].

I've found [capnix](http://capnix.com) to host the website but now need the 'Geo'-portion. [CartoDB's](http://cartodb.com/pricing) 5MB data limit is too small for my project needs and OpenGeo's [Cloud Edition](http://opengeo.org/products/suite/cloud/) is too short (3 days!). Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are not tied to GeoServer, you might take a look at a very new [QGIS-based](http://www.qgis.org) solution called [QGIS Cloud](http://qgiscloud.com/pages/quickstart). It is currently free. Not sure about the speed, as their server, I think, is in Germany (though they may be expanding soon).

Answer (score 5):

I searched for the same free cloud based geoweb services and came up empty over a year ago. Ended up using [www.webfaction.com](http://www.webfaction.com/) for about $10 a month. They supply PostGreSQL, PostGIS and all of the necessary libraries. Had my IT nephew install GeoServer and all is well, so far.

I'm fairly new to web/map development and I found the support to be most helpful and quick to respond.

Answer (score 5):

- [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) have a free usage tier that lasts a year for new customers.  You could install your own software and would be great for learning the different parts of a typical stack.
- [Google Fusion tables](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/Home/) is free and should be possible to plugin to openlayers.

Answer (score 3):

You could try arcgis online. There is a free level for non commercial use

Good summary here:
http://www.georelated.com/2012/10/cloud-web-mapping-service-api-review.html

Answer (score 1):

You are probably out of luck for "free" but you could also check out HostGIS. http://www.hostgis.com/home/. We've has sites running with them for years. Good support and all round nice guy running it.