# How to run GDAL command in php page?

Tags: qgis, gdal, php

I want to develop a webportal that will show the QGIS generated images on dynamic website.
For this reason I need to run `gdal_translate` command inside php page. but I don't know is it possible or not. If possible than please let me know how to do this and if not possible than please give any alternative solution in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

Enamul, QGIS offers a [WMS server component](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial), which has an optional [QGIS GeoExt web client interface](https://github.com/qgis/qgis-web-client) ([demos here](http://webgis.uster.ch/)), or you can utilize the QGIS WMS output as a layer in an [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) map.

Also, there is a nice plugin to integrate QGIS Server with a PHP server: [lizmap](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/lizmapplugin/wiki). lizmap is available via the [plugin installer](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/python_in_qgis_tutorial1.html), but you will have to [manually add the new QGIS repository to installer](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Python_Plugin_Repositories) if using QGIS version < 1.8.0.

Comment: Dakcarto,thanks for your answer but if you can give more detail solution as I am new to qgis and gdal if possible any examples than it will be more helpful for me.

Comment: [QGIS Server – A WMS Server for the masses « Linfiniti Geo Blog](http://linfiniti.com/2010/08/qgis-mapserver-a-wms-server-for-the-masses/) - Also, you might want to look into the [QGIS Cloud plugin](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24216/6725), which could be embedded in your web portal within an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). But if you are on shared hosting this is probably disabled.

Comment: johanvdw,it looks good, can you give a sample code which is executing gdal command with exec

Comment: @EnamulHaque take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36890338/why-cant-php-insert-new-geometry-on-postgis

Answer (score 1):

Open the folder which is containing "gdal_translate", just copy that file and paste in the same folder. And then rename that copied file with "gdaltranslate" (just remove ' _ ' ). Use the renamed file (i.e., gdaltranslate ) in your php code ... and that works :) njy