# How to publish my map on the web?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, qgis-web-client

I want to publish my map  is created in QGIS 1.7.4 version on to the web.Can u pls suggest me how to publish the map with proper documentaion and screen shots if possible?

Comment: The answer heavily depends on *how* you want to publish your map online - the spectrum of possibilities ranges from exporting a simple *.jpg and putting it on your website to creating a dynamic webservice a la Google maps, either with tiled raster data or true vector data.

Comment: You may want to consider [Looking for a FREE Cloud based 'Web Mapping Stack' Host](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24213/looking-for-a-free-cloud-based-web-mapping-stack-host), specifically the info on QGIS Cloud.

Answer (score 3):

use Quantum GIS (QGIS) Web Client [here](https://github.com/qgis/qgis-web-client) and QGIS Server which @Gabriel Giroux stated above.

> A WMS based webgis client that makes use of QGIS specific WMS
>   extensions (e.g. highlighting, printing, metadata, etc.). QGIS
>   webclient reads the configuration from the WMS GetCapabilities command
>   and builds the layer tree accordingly. Supports legend graphic,
>   feature info requests and printing.
>
> The client builds on existing Web-GIS libraries OpenLayers and GeoExt,
>   as well as ExtJS 3 for the GUI widgets.

[image: gis-browser]

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 3):

MapServer is also an open-source (free option) that requires an Apache Web Server.  There are tutorials at www.mapserver.org as well as installation instructions, and plenty of examples.

Answer (score 2):

Before publishing your QGIS project make sure that you have QGIS Server up and running. To accomplish that process I recommande you to have a look to this link below that explain step by step how to install ang configure QGIS server.

http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial

Comment: Is qgis server only for WMS or can it be used to host actual weblinks containing qgis maps? I would like to use it to provide data links to non-GIS users...