# Setting up QGIS Server at low cost for small user community?

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, apache, hosting

I want to setup QGIS Server at a low cost for a small user community (mainly me).

Parameters:

1. Some data is private so something like qgis cloud not an option (not enough money for paid option).
2. Primarily only me using this for experimentation. Sometimes I would like to share with a few other interested parties who may be scattered around the world.
3. Maybe one day I come up with something really interesting/useful and would like the option to scale up server capacity quite quickly in case it generates a lot of traffic.
4. Not too worried about 100% uptime - but equally don't want something that is falling over all the time. Essentially I can cope with the odd outage if it means its cheap.
5. Needs to be cheap.... ideally free.
6. Needs to be relatively simple to implement OR with a good tutorial. I have dabbled with this sort of thing before but still get a bit confused with too much server jargon & command line stuff - keen to learn at least!

QGIS server looks ideal because most of my work is in QGIS desktop and I want something that is relatively quick and easy to publish to.

Things I am considering:

1. Trying to setup QGIS Server on existing shared hostgator server... (but looking unlikely i can get sudo access).
2. Converting an old laptop into a home server.
3. Using Amazon EC2.
4. Try to setup QGIS Server on a bitnami stack and then use their cloud (maybe free option will work here?)
5. Finding a new low cost host option (could stretch to £10-20 a month at a push as a last resort)

Has anybody else faced a similar scenario? Can you suggest solutions that might work for me?

Many thanks in advance if so....

Comment: A likely duplicate of [Looking for a FREE Cloud based 'Web Mapping Stack' Host](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24213/looking-for-a-free-cloud-based-web-mapping-stack-host), at least in the general sense of the question.

Comment: One other option, listed only in the comments by @Erick in the answer by "pgager" is [OpenShift by RedHat](https://www.openshift.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) as a host, it's really cheap, like, $5 per month. Super simple web-interface for starting machines, you can add SSH keys to make it secure, it's just right for testing VMs.

I have no affiliation with DigitalOcean.

I can give you [$10 referral credits](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=9a3c032c376c). (Disclaimer, I get something out of it if you continue to use it, see [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/referral-program/).)

Once you have a server, you could follow [this guide](http://anitagraser.com/2012/03/30/qgis-server-on-ubuntu-step-by-step/) to get it set up.

Depending on what OS you use, you need to get files on the server, you could use github to version-control your files and a workflow there to get stuff up on the server, or you can just use WinSCP or a some other SFTP client.

Finally, when you have projects in QGIS Server, you can use OpenLayers to view them, but [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) is easier.

Comment: worked for me. not sure if I can still give you credit retrospectively as I signed up without going through your referral link in the first instance (thought I would have the opportunity to enter your code). If you know how to do this I will update!

Comment: Doesn't matter! Glad it worked out.